# Comparing source to target and then comparing target to source once again in a merge?

Tags: sql, merge

I was looking at a merge script and noticed that the script updates if the source.column is different from the target.column.

What I don't understand is why they have two checks, one to check if the source.column is different than the target.column and then another to check if the target.column is different than the source.column.

The second NULLIF's which compare target to source seem redundant to me...

Does anyone know if there is there a reason for this?

```
WHEN MATCHED AND (
   NULLIF(Source.[code], Target.[code]) IS NOT NULL OR NULLIF(Target.[code], Source.[code]) IS NOT NULL OR 
   NULLIF(Source.[descE], Target.[descE]) IS NOT NULL OR NULLIF(Target.[descE], Source.[descE]) IS NOT NULL THEN
UPDATE SET
  [code] = Source.[code], 
  [descE] = Source.[descE]
```

Script works, but I assume I could remove every second NULLIF and the script would still work the same?

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth I agree with you. If I were in your situation, I would run the merge script on some test databases with the second and fourth nullif()s removed to make sure I received the results I was expecting before making the change.